# Is "Left Wing, Right Wing" trophy bugged?

Tags: achievements, rocket-league

The trophy's description states:

> Win a Snow Day match with both the Blue and Orange teams

I've won every type of Snow Day match: against bots, against a friend, alone... The trophy does not come out.

I tried changing my teams back to "Blue" and "Orange" but it didn't work.

Is there a solution or should I give up? Any suggestion?

Comment: Among all those wins, have they all been on one team color? Blue or Orange?

Comment: @n_palum Of course. Apparently I solved it by playing by each team and win on both arenas.

Comment: Odd - then again a bunch of Rocket League's achievements are finicky

Comment: @n_palum Usually my problems are due to bad translated descriptions, but this one seems pretty defective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you play with each team and win on both arenas you'll get the trophy. This worked for me.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it yourself to let other people know.

Comment: @F1Krazy totally forgot I answered it